# encodeNameReplacements not working in page editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms, page-editor

The sitecore configuration code below works well in normal mode.

```
    <encodeNameReplacements>
      <replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />
    </encodeNameReplacements>
```

In Page editor mode the (Spaces) " " or not replaced with "-".

In Page Editor Mode:
If i try to remove image and insert new one; image is not displayed until i saved the page because the  (Spaces) " " or not replaced with "-".

[image][image]

Am i missing anything, any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with the `encodeNameReplacements` messing up the media paths until I found **[this article](http://getfishtank.ca/blog/sitecore-7-2-upgrade-encoding-media-library-item-names)**.

After implementing this code in our project a `dash` will replace the `%20` and the media images will still render.

### Sitecore 7.2 Upgrade Media Library Gotcha

http://getfishtank.ca/blog/sitecore-7-2-upgrade-encoding-media-library-item-names

While upgrading a client to Sitecore 7.2 this section of the release notes gave us pause:

### Media API

When rendering media URLs, the system **did not use** the configuration in the `encodeNameReplacements` section to replace special characters in the URLs.

This **has been fixed** so that media URLs **also use** the `encodeNameReplacements` configuration. (323105, 314977)

### Summary:

media library URLs now use the `encodeNameReplacements` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If any one run into this problem; Look for any custom media code written on your site. I got the below custom code causing the problem:

```
 public class MediaProvider : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider 
        {
            public override string GetMediaUrl(Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem item, Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions options)
            {
                string url = base.GetMediaUrl(item, options);

                if (!(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal && options.UseItemPath))
                {
                    return url;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Working when Changed to**

```
public class MediaProvider : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider 
    {
        public override string GetMediaUrl(Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem item, Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions options)
        {
            string url = base.GetMediaUrl(item, options);

            if (options.UseItemPath)
            {
                return url;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal && Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor` does not make sense, it will always return false, the page cannot be in both modes at the same time.